# How to dynamically adapt the layout by using only CSS

Tags: css

Depending by the size of the app interface, I need to adapt dynamically the layout by using only CSS.
It will be possible?

If the width of my app is 500px, I'd like to display the 3 containers in this way:

```
            | A   B |  // width 500px
            |   C   |
```

If the width of my app is 750px, I'd like to display the 3 containers in this way:

```
            |  A  B  C  | // width 750px
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/60/).

By clicking on the button "change app size" you can change the size of the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS media queries:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 500px)" href="css/mobile-500.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 750px)" href="css/mobile-750.css" />
```

Comment: What can happen if the browser doesn't support css media queries? (IE8 for example)

Comment: Then it only loads `style.css`. Try it and see, as IE is a wild beast.

Answer (score 4):

Using CSS3 Media Queries, yes you can.

```
@media (min-width:500px) { ... }
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to look into css media queries. Check out this link - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/